# Root of $y(x)$ satisfying $\frac{dy}{dx}+y\exp(x)+1\le0$ in $[0,\frac{3}{4}]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

> Question: Let $y(x)$ be a continuously differentiable function of $x$ such that $y(0)=1$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}+y\exp(x)+1\le0.$ Then state (True of False) for the following:   $y(x)$ never attains the  value $0$ in $[0,\frac{3}{4}].$

If we choose $y(x)=1$ as in the given initial condition ,the given inequality leads to absurdity for every choice of $x\in \mathbb R.$ Why would the existence of such $y(x)$ will come? I think there is no such $y(x)$ ,so the given statement is false.

Thanks.

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't quite stack up. You don't have a choice in the function $y$. What the question asks is if such a function with these properties exists, then does this function attain a zero on the closed interval $[0, 3/4]$? It might be possible that no such $y$ exists, but that does not invalidate the question.

Comment: I agree my reasoning is incomplete. My concern is just that both the initial criteria ( I have used $y(0)=1$ only) and the given inequality, both can never happen together. If there is no such $y(x)$, how can this be a valid question?@MathsMatador

Comment: Unless I am mistaken do all functions $y(x) = 1-mx$ with $m \ge 2$ satisfy the differential inequality and have a zero in $[0, 1/2]$.

Comment: Sir @MartinR, yes it works. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR you seem to be right, but there is an issue that it is not mentioned what is the domain of the differential inequality. If that is also equal to $[0,3/4]$ then it is right.

Comment: @AasthaChoudhary We do not need the function to be equal to the value of the initial condition at every point $x$, only at $x=0$. The inequality at $x=0$ holds if $\frac{dy}{dx}(0)+y(0)e^0+1 = \frac{dy}{dx} + 1 +1 = \frac{dy}{dx}+2 \leq 0$, that is $\frac{dy}{dx}(0) \leq -2$. This can be achieved for let's say $y(x) = 1-2x$. You still have to show that the inequality holds for all $x$ (it does not, check $x = -1/2$).

Comment: I realized my mistake. @KoenZeven

Comment: @AasthaChoudhary: I have added a short *explanation* of the proof to my answer (just in case that you are interested).

Comment: Thanks again, sir @MartinR :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us denote the interval $[0, 3/4]$ with $I$. The following is true:

> *Every* differentiable function $y:I \to \Bbb R$ which satisfies $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(x) + e^x y(x) + 1 \le 0$ for all $x \in I$ has a zero in $I$.

*Remark #1:* Such functions do exist, for example $y(x) = 1-mx$ with $m \ge 2$.

*Remark #2:* The idea is that the diffential inequality gives an upper bound for $y'$, which leads to an upper bound for $y$. The factor $e^x$ makes explicit integration difficult, therefore we omit that factor, and get a weaker bound. But that is still good enough to prove that $y$ can not be positive everywhere in $I$.

*Proof:* Assume that $y$ has no zero, so that $y(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$. Then
$$
 y'(x) + y(x) \le y'(x) + e^xy(x) \le -1
$$
or
$$
 \frac{d}{dx} (e^x y(x)) \le -e^x \, .
$$
It follows that
$$ 
 e^x y(x) - 1  \le \int_0^x (-e^t) \, dt = 1-e^x
$$
and therefore
$$
 0 < y(x) \le 2 e^{-x} -1
$$
for all $x \in I$. But that is not possible because $2 e^{-3/4} -1 \approx -0.055 < 0$.